# What can cause a service to switch from 'automatic' startup to  to 'manual' startup?

Tags: windows-server-2008, service, windows-service

We had some problem with the Windows Time Service a while ago. It was set to 'manual' startup and was not started. We set this to 'automatic' startup on every server and configured it properly to sync with the domain controller.

Today, we have one server that fell back from 'automatic' startup to 'manual'. And it stopped. What is the possible reason for this? It was unable to contact the domain controller?

I could not find anything in the logs about this configuration switch...

Thanks

Comment: Not sure but to be safe I'd recommend enforcing that setting via Group Policy

Answer (score 0):

Having it set to manual is normal when it's configured to sync "on a scheduled basis".

You'll find that there's a scheduled task in the Task Scheduler Library (Microsoft -> Windows -> Time Synchronization) that starts the service manually for a sync.

Comment: I can see the task, it's set to be executed every sunday at 1AM. This might explain our problems. We will setup this task to sync the time once a day and I'll keep you posted if that fix the problem. We are currently having issues with an incorrectly synced time between a web application and an appfabric cache cluster.